# my state change when I set it, but my other component which use this state value through the react context don't show the state with the new result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state

I have a state being declared inside a context provider and one component A set this state and other component B just read... but when I change the state with the component A, the component B doesn't show the new value, keep showing the initial value! how I solve that, please?

**context file:**

```
export const SearchContext = React.createContext();

export const SearchProvider = (props) => {
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState({
      content: "Matrix", });  

    return (
      <SearchContext.Provider value={{ searchInput, setSearchInput }}>
          {props.children}
      </SearchContext.Provider>
     );
};
```

**form component(component A in the question):**

```
export default () => {

  const history = useHistory()
  **const {searchInput, setSearchInput} = React.useContext(SearchContext);**

  function search (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 

    history.push('/resultado-de-busca')
     const searchContent = document.querySelector(`[data-input-search]`).value;
 setSearchInput({...searchInput, content:searchContent })
        
  }



  return (
    <form className="search" data-search onSubmit={search}>
      <input data-input-search placeholder="Digite o nome desejado..." type="text"  />
    </form>
  );
};
```

component A is called inside a Header.js component and inside the SearchProvider that way:

```
<SearchProvider>
             <SearchForm/>
 </SearchProvider>
```

**page component (component B in the question, where is rendered the result):**

```
 const {searchInput} = React.useContext(SearchContext);

console.log(searchInput.content):

// results: 'Matrix' instead of the new value changed in Component A
```

component B is called inside the App.js from React, and inside the SearchProvider that way:

```
<SearchProvider>
             <SearchPage/>
 </SearchProvider>
```

Comment: is `SearchProvider` being used twice as a parent of `App.js` and a parent of `SearchPage`?

Comment: no, just as parent of SearchPage, I must put it as parent of App component in the index.js?

Comment: no I was just confused with where it was actually being used. It needs to be the parent of any component that is going to use it

Comment: aaaah, I figure it out with your question. my problem was I declared SearchProvider 2 times, one in app.js as a parent of my searchPage and the other time inside my header component... changed this to encapsulate all the app.js with just one SearchProvider, and it works... Thanks WebbH!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a single Provider tag is used twice in two different places in a single app.
To solve this issue, Use the Provider tag as a root tag in App.js.